# Delete sensitive credentials in slack automaticly

Tags: slack

I'm looking for a solution or GitHub code that searches on a regular basis Slack and finds sensitive credentials (user name, password, etc) that employee shares in channels, and delete it.
Can you assist me?

Answer (score 0):

There is no finished solution here. You can write code based on [slack_cleaner2](https://github.com/sgratzl/slack_cleaner2).
Channel communication is now handled by [Conversations API](https://api.slack.com/docs/conversations-api) and everything is described here.